# In ArangoDB, how can I use the "AND" keywords in a view search query to concatenate multiple conditions?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I tried to use the `SEARCH` keywords in `Arangodb` with `PHRASE` function to conduct a fuzzy search query in a view, and the problem is that if I tried to use the AND keyword to add multiple searches conditions it will only return an empty set, is there something wrong in my query?

```
FOR a in newView
    SEARCH (a.LocationStreet.StreetNumberText == 18 AND PHRASE( a.StreetName, "GREY", "text_en") AND PHRASE(a.eng, "St.Johns", "text_en") )
    FOR v, e, p IN 5 OUTBOUND a GRAPH 'Dwellings'
        SORT BM25 (a) desc
        LIMIT 10
    RETURN [BM25(a),p.vertices]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question for better response.

Comment: Is it working with only `PHRASE( a.StreetName, "GREY", "text_en") AND PHRASE(a.eng, "St.Johns", "text_en")` in the SEARCH ?